# Laravel validation rule "different"

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I am having a hard time understanding this validation rule. Basically, I have two fields, and they are both `nullable`. But, once both fields are filled, they have to be different from each other. I cannot enter `test` in both of them, for example. This validation rule works, if I fill `both` fields.

But, when I only fill `one` of the fields, the validation fails and says the fields should be different from each other with the following message:

```
The name and replace must be different.
```

I checked what is being submitted to my Form Request, and this is the following:

```
"name" => null
"replace" => "test"
```

Stripped version of my validation rules:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'different:replace|nullable',
        'replace' => 'different:name|nullable',
    ];
}
```

Can somebody explain to me what I am misunderstanding with this validation rule? Do `null` values not count with this rule?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take a look at the `validateDifferent` function from `Illuminate\Validation\Concerns\ValidatesAttributes` (`vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Concerns/ValidatesAttributes.php:432`) rule:

```
public function validateDifferent($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    $this->requireParameterCount(1, $parameters, 'different');

    foreach ($parameters as $parameter) {
        $other = Arr::get($this->data, $parameter);

        if (is_null($other) || $value === $other) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

As you can see in the if case, the rule will fail if the other value is null.

```
if (is_null($other) || $value === $other)
```

Comment: Shoudl've checked there.. At least learned something new, thanks :)

Comment: @Hardist Np have a nice day! :)